# How to run tasks and display a progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to run a couple tasks (ex. making folders) in my WinForms, and displaying progress using a progress bar I made.
Currently this is the code, but I'm trying to make the progress bar end when the tasks have finished.

Code snippet:

```
private void ProgressTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadingBar.Width += 2;
            if (loadingBar.Width >= 492)
            {
                ProgressTimer.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Progress shouldn't be based on how many times you've `Ticked()`.  CALCULATE your progress based on how many folders you've made, then set your control accordingly.

Comment: Hello, perhaps  [the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/code-samples-csharp/tree/master/CancellationToken) shows a very basics for doing a ProgressBar asynchronously. Note it's not a answer but a possible path to use.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Where is the problem? What would you like to change?

Comment: Are the tasks `async`?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and add details on how the processing is done. Are they on the main thread, or using a `BaackgroundWorker` or using the `async/await`.

Answer (score 0):

First you can just Drag and Drop the progressbar onto your form.`

[image: enter code here]`

With `progressbar1.Value = 40` will you set the bar to 40, for example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of code that loops through a fixed number of times with a progress bar and a cancelation option. The start button has three functions

- **Go** - system is ready and button starts the work.
- **Cancel** - system is processing work and button cancels.
- **Clear** - work is complete or canceled and button resets the system.

And the corresponding WinForms controls

[image: scr1]

[image: scr2]

```
public enum OperationState
{
    Ready,     // System is ready
    Busy,      // System is busy
    Finished   // System has finished/canceled work
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private OperationState state;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        State = OperationState.Ready;
    }
    public OperationState State
    {
        get => state;
        set
        {
            UpdateForm(value);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateForm(OperationState state)
    {
        // check if this is from not the main thread.
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // invoke this menthd from the main thread
            this.Invoke(
                new Action<OperationState>(UpdateForm),
                new object[] { state });

            return;
        }
        this.state = state;
        label1.Text = state.ToString();
        switch (state)
        {
            case OperationState.Ready:
                
                button1.Text = "Go";
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                break;
            case OperationState.Busy:
                button1.Text = "Cancel";
                break;
            case OperationState.Finished:
                button1.Text = "Clear";
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cts == null && State == OperationState.Ready)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();                
            int total = 1000;
            progressBar1.Maximum = total;
            IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>((iter) =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = iter;
            });
            var token = cts.Token;
            await Task.Run(async () =>
           {
               State = OperationState.Busy;
               for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
               {
                   // do the work
                   await Task.Delay(10);                       
                   progress.Report(i + 1);
                   // check for cancelation
                   if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }
               State = OperationState.Finished;
           }, token);
        }
        else if (State == OperationState.Busy)
        {
            // issue calcelation request
            cts.Cancel();
            State = OperationState.Finished;
        }
        else
        {
            // reset system
            cts = null;
            State = OperationState.Ready;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (State == OperationState.Busy && e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Form is busy. Try again later.", "Form Closing");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```